# Over time what happens to soluble liquids with different densities

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions, mixtures, density

I have a case with two liquids: Water and another chemical which is miscible in water. 
The chemical has a density of 800 g/l so it's 20% less dense than water.

Initially the chemical was mixed with the water but now it has been sitting stagnant for 20 years.

Since such a long time has passed what could I expect to see in terms of the mixing of the liquids? Will the different densities have caused the two liquids to separate? Will there still be a trace of the chemical dissolved in the water?

Comment: Vodka is pretty much a binary mix of ethanol $(ρ = \pu{789 g L-1})$ and water. I have a 1970s bottle of [Stoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolichnaya) from my grandfather and it's still a homogeneous ready-to-drink solution. So no, unless there were some chemical reactions involved resulting in building up of a residue of third component, there is likely no reason for a mix of miscible liquids to split.

Comment: If the liquids are miscible, I would expect no separation at all.

Comment: If they were gasses then gravity will have an effect, but a column of gas kilometres high will be needed. Density will vary as $\rho=\rho_0 \exp(-Mg\Delta H/(RT))$ with $g$ acceleration due to gravity, $M$ molar mass (kg/mole) and $\Delta H$ elevation ( metres). You could increase the force used to separate  by using a centrifuge.